# PHP not parsing 1000, 10000, 100000, etc. **Fixed**

Tags: floating-point, php-5.3

I am using the following code to take HTML $_POST vars [type:text] representing min & max price, sanitize and strip "$" and ",", commit them to $_SESSION and then use them for a MySQL query against data in a column of type "Float". The code is as follows...

```
//The locale I'm using
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8'); 

//The minimum price is handled
//Sanitized POST var to SESSION var
$_SESSION['minprice'] = filter_var($_POST['minprice'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED); 
// Strip currency symbol and commas
$_SESSION['minprice'] = str_replace(array(',','$'),array('',''),$_SESSION['minprice']); 
//SESSION var to local float var for SQL query
$minprice = floatval($_SESSION['minprice']); 

//The same is done for the maximum price
//Sanitized POST var to SESSION var
$_SESSION['maxprice'] = filter_var($_POST['maxprice'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED); 
// Strip currency symbol and commas
$_SESSION['maxprice'] = str_replace(array(',','$'),array('',''),$_SESSION['maxprice']); 
//SESSION var to local float var for SQL query
$maxprice = floatval($_SESSION['maxprice']); 

//The SQL query
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ';
$sql .= "zip like '$searchzip%' "; //Ignore this
$sql .= "&& sellprice >= '$minprice' ";
$sql .= "&& sellprice <= '$maxprice' ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY id DESC";
```

$minprice and $maxprice are then compared to a value from the MySQL table and the result is handled accordingly, basically $minprice <= $sellprice <= $maxprice.

For the variable $sellprice = 12.01, the following search queries will return rows from the MySQL database:

The following returns rows wonderfully.
($minprice, $maxprice)
0, 13
0.00, 13.00
$0.00, $13.00
$10.00, $12.02
$0.00, $12111
$0.00, $82711

The following will not return rows, don't know why.
($minprice, $maxprice)
0, 100
0, 1000 - 1000000 and beyond
0, 1,000 - 1,000,000 and beyond
0, 111 // I thought it was just an issue with 0's or commas being parsed incorrectly
$0.00, $111 - $111111 and beyond
10, 11112 //Note that 12111 returns rows above

I must be missing something here, probably something fundamental and silly. I would very much appreciate any help that people are willing to give, thank you.

If you'd like to take a look at the site itself the URL is http://listing.dyndns.org, it's nothing special but it's my beginner's project.

**Edit0: There is only one listing on there currently, search for it in the 99208 zip code.**

**Edit1: used the expression 'select id from tablename where sellprice >= 0 && sellprice <= 111111.11;' and it returned all the right rows, so I know data in the database is OK. Must be my PHP.**

**Edit2: Looks like only the numbers before the first comma or decimal are being evaluated against what's in the database. I am so lost.**

**Fixed: Read a great post on here about the badness that ensues when stories monetary values in a FLOAT column rather than a DECIMAL column. Changed the column type to DECIMAL(9,2) and cast the PHP variables explicitly using (int). Now the values are stored perfectly and doing comparison operations against the database values works great. Hope this is useful to someone.**

Answer (score 0):

setlocale is under php 5.3 deprecated and has no effect when it returns false!